# Interior of the union

Tags: general-topology

Hi this was a question in my exam and i can't solve it i search and i founed equivalence relation between the equality of the union and the boundary of these sets and i still can't solve it. my teacher said to me it less than 5  line any help?
Let$ A,B \subset X$ where $\bar A \cap B = \bar B \cap A =  \emptyset $
Proof that $ \operatorname{int}(A \cup B)=\operatorname{int}(A)\cup \operatorname{int}(B).$

Answer (score 0):

By hypothesis, no point in A is in the closure of B and no point in B is in the closure of A, so the interior of A and that of B are disjoint sets. This implies the required equality.